# What should I do first for NLP related task?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec

I am a sort of newbie to NLP world.
But anyway, I have just started my NLP project.

My task is about inferring hidden sentence in a paragraph.
Let me show you an example question.

[a multiple choice question about inferring a clause in the blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOto1.png)
I want my machine learning model to extract some meaningful phrase from the given text(in above image, a paragraph)

I know that my question sounds quite ambiguous for you all. I just want to know even a small clue.

Thank you for your response in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Skip-thought vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06726) are a system for predicting sentences from a context, by essentially constructing sentence-wide vectors. Might be useful, especially so in combination with context2vec if you want to build a custom model.